# Confusion in Grails Embedded variables

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I saw this in Grails documentation

```
static mappings = {
   "/$blog/$year/$month/$day/$id"(controller: "blog", action: "show")
}
The above mapping would let you do things like:

/graemerocher/2007/01/10/my_funky_blog_entry
The individual tokens in the URL would again be mapped into the params object with values available for year, month, day, id and so on.
```

I have doubt is, if i have one more mapping just different is **/$day/&month( above /$month/$day )**. Even same path is valid for my new mapping also, then how it identifies which dynamic mapping and how to bind to **params** object.

Answer (score 0):

if there is no clear single mapping (e.g. overlap) the mapping, which is most specific, wins (least wildcards, most static parts).  at last the order in your urlmappings decides.

pre-edit (see comments, wrong example):
see https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-web-url-mappings/src/test/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/mapping/OverlappingUrlMappingsMatchingSpec.groovy

Comment: In the test you've linked to it's not the ordering that determines which of the two mappings wins, it's the fact that one is considered "more specific" than the other (where "more specific" means (1) fewer `**` double wildcards, or (2) fewer single-wildcards, or (3) more static segments, in that order).

Comment: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/URL-Mapping-question-td3556768.html#a3565451 is my decoding of the source code for the specificity rules.

Answer (score 0):

You should never define 2 mappings like this:

```
"/$day/$month"(controller: 'one', action: 'index')

"/$month/$day"(controller: 'two', action: 'index')
```

A problem with that is that there is no way to ever distinguish between them for forward URL mappings.  If a request comes into something like `/5/6`, there is no good way for the framework to decide which one to use.  You could use named mappings which helps with reverse URL lookups, but the forward mappings would still be a problem.  You need something that makes them unique in order for them to make sense.  They could have a different prefix, or constraints but it doesn't make sense to have 2 separate mappings like those I described above.  There is no way for the framework to make sense of those.

Comment: Think of it from the perspective of someone typing in a URL.  If you were describing to someone the way to invoke the action for February 5, would you tell them to submit to `/2/5` or `/5/2`.  Same question about May 2.  Those same to patterns would seem to be valid answers for that date.  You just can't do it with the mappings I described.